# Quasi-disjoint subsets of an infinite cardinal

Tags: set-theory

Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal and let $S$ be a collection of subsets of $\kappa$ such that for $s\neq t\in S$ we have $|s\cap t| \leq 1$. Is it possible that $|S|>\kappa$?

Comment: (Follow-up [question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/198950/6085) at MO.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume AC:

For each $a \in \kappa$, let $S_a = \{s \in S: a \in s\}$. The intersection of two sets in $S_a$ must be $\{a\}$, so by picking an element that isn't $a$ from each set, and $a$ from $\{a\}$ if it's in $S_a$, we have an injection $S_a \hookrightarrow \kappa$.

And we can write $S = \cup_{a \in \kappa}S_a$. This injects into $\sqcup_{a\in\kappa}S_a$, which injects into $\kappa \times \kappa$, which injects into $\kappa$, and so $|S| \leq \kappa$.

Comment: Where did you need choice?

Comment: @GME Constructing the injections $S_a \hookrightarrow \kappa$ uses choice, as does constructing the injection $\cup S_a \hookrightarrow \sqcup S_a$. I don't know if this was necessary, though.

Comment: I'm not sure it is. We can map each element of $S_\alpha$ to the least ordinal it contains which is not equal to $\alpha$ (otherwise we map it to $\alpha$). And assuming that $\sqcup S_\alpha = \{\langle \alpha, x\rangle: \alpha\in x\}$, we can map each $x\in S$ to $\langle \alpha, x\rangle$ where $\alpha$ is its least element.

Comment: In other words, we let $f(x) = \langle \alpha, \beta\rangle$ where $\alpha$ is the least ordinal in $x$ and $\beta$ is the least ordinal in $x$ not equal to $\alpha$ if there is one, other wise $\beta = \alpha$. Then $f$ is 1-1 into $\kappa\times\kappa$ for the reasons you've given.

Comment: @GME Sure, if $\kappa$ is well-ordered to start with. If you don't have choice then not every cardinal is the cardinality of an ordinal, though, so you can't necessarily well-order $\kappa$.

Comment: It depends what we mean by cardinal, as usual. I was assuming $\kappa$ was an ordinal.